# App Script + Forms: How to move upload files

Tags: javascript

I have a Form bound to a Sheet. That works fine. I need to move the uploads to the newFolder and delete them from the temp holding folder.

I have it split into 2 functions. They work independently but I can not get them to work together. I think I just don't know enough.

So I could use some help sorting this out.

Thanks

```js
//this part works great
function autoFillForm(e) {
  
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var firstName = e.values[1];
  var lastName = e.values[2];
  var title = e.values[3];
  

 //create new folder
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('My Parent Folder ID');
  var newFolder = parentFolder.createFolder(lastName + ' - ' + firstName);


  //Get template
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('My Template ID'); 
  

  //Copy template, name it, save to new folder
  var copy = file.makeCopy(lastName + ',' + firstName + ' - ' + 'Template Name', newFolder); 
  
  //Open copied file
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()); 
  
  //Get Template body
  var body = doc.getBody(); 
  
  //Replace text in template
  body.replaceText('{{fName}}', firstName);
  body.replaceText('{{lName}}', lastName);
  body.replaceText('{{title}}', title);
  
  //Save and close
  doc.saveAndClose(); 
}
```

**UPDATE**
I was able to get this working and it moves the files but only in a stand alone script. I have been trying for hours to get it to work with the main scripts and I'm at a loss.

```js
function movingFiles (e){

  //get file names from source folder
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(ID for Source Folder).getFiles();
  
  while(files.hasNext())
  {
  var file = files.next();
  }

  //get file ID
  var fileId = file.getId();

  //move file, clean source folder
  DriveApp.getFolderById(newFolder).addFile(file);
  file
    .getParents()
    .next()
    .removeFile(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TLDR:
this: DriveApp.getFolderById(newFolder).addFile(file);
to this: DriveApp.getFolderById(newFolder.getId()).addFile(file);

this: (newFolder)
to this: (newFolder.getId())

I feel kind of stupid because this was an easy answer in the end.
I am able to to do everything in the one function. No need for seperate functions of Global Variables.

```js
  //this part works great
  function autoFillForm(e) {
  
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var firstName = e.values[1];
  var lastName = e.values[2];
  var title = e.values[3];
  

  //create new folder
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('My Parent Folder ID');
  var newFolder = parentFolder.createFolder(lastName + ' - ' + firstName);


  //Get template
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('My Template ID'); 
  

  //Copy template, name it, save to new folder
  var copy = file.makeCopy(lastName + ',' + firstName + ' - ' + 'Template Name', 
  newFolder); 
  
  //Open copied file
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()); 
  
  //Get Template body
  var body = doc.getBody(); 
  
  //Replace text in template
  body.replaceText('{{fName}}', firstName);
  body.replaceText('{{lName}}', lastName);
  body.replaceText('{{title}}', title);
  
  //Save and close
  doc.saveAndClose(); 
 
  

  //get file names from source folder
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(ID for Source Folder).getFiles();
  
  while(files.hasNext())
  {
  var file = files.next();
  }

  //get file ID
  var fileId = file.getId();


  //error here

  //move file, clean source folder
  DriveApp.getFolderById(newFolder).addFile(file);
  file
    .getParents()
    .next()
    .removeFile(file);

  //this is where I was making a mistake
  //this: DriveApp.getFolderById(newFolder).addFile(file);
  //to this: DriveApp.getFolderById(newFolder.getId()).addFile(file);
  //I was failing to understand I needed to define the function to the var again


}
```