# Google App Script - Docs - Removing unused Items After Merging Content - RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a Google Form bound to a Sheet. My Script is in the sheet. Sometimes a set of fields in the Form will be blank / not filled in, this is intentional.

When this happens I want to remove these unused merging elements from the Doc before saving and closing it. There can be 7 to 20 unused elements that I want to remove when this happens.

I have tried so many things. I do not want to hard code it as there will be changes made/ other additions made moving forward. This would be an easy fix but not a correct solution.

I am thinking the RegEx after the merge is the way to go, but I'm open to any suggestions.

The Fields are formatted like this: {{NAME}} or {{OtherName}} or {{Some Name}} or {{Street Name}}, {{State Name}} as in an address. I am also trying to remove any extra spaces and am struggling as to how to remove the ",". Maybe I should be adding the "," when merging the field instead of it being a static part of the page.

Here is my RegEx. I'm new to it and tried following the GAS guide to build this:

```js
body.replaceText(/([{]{2}|^)[\w.]\s{0,1}[\w.]{0,1}([}]{2}|$)/ , '');

//OR

body.replaceText(/(\W\W|^)[\w.]\s{0,1}[\w.]{0,1}(\W\W|$)/ , '');

//OR

var pattern = /([{]{2}|^)[\w.]\s{0,1}[\w.]{0,1}([}]{2}$)/;
body.replaceText(pattern , '');
```

I have spent hours on this issue trying Start and End, loops and any other solution I could think of or find to adapt to my need and am at my wits end.

Thanks

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your current issue and your goal from your question. So, in order to help correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the images?

Comment: How about this: `/{{.*?}}(\s*,\s*){0,1}/` ?

Comment: Thanks. I am trying now, did not work the first time but I am super new so it might take me a few tries to get it right. This is a link to a simple view of my code. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72729574/app-script-forms-how-to-move-upload-files)

Comment: Hi JohnDee! Is there any chance you could show me this in a sample loop? Or have a link to a sample loop using regex method to find multiple instances in the body? Thank you. This is so much more elegant than my crude attempt and it works.